# What is a typical response rate to a survey of academics?

Tags: survey

Suppose I sent out a survey to all of the authors who published at major venues in my field, and N% of them responded.

For what N would this be considered a success?
For what N would the response bias be considered a critical flaw?

Under what criteria would it be reasonable to use this survey to support statements about the attitudes of researchers in this field?

Comment: I suspect the first N will be far below the second N for any unsolicited survey. I've seen a huge range depending on topic and originator. I think most people receiving this sort of message will find it as rude. Make sure you get IRB approval before doing human subjects research.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/187423/ethical-implications-of-using-scraped-e-mail-addresses-for-survey